# Total war Warhammer - Wood Elves defending Lookouts far from the Forest

Tags: warhammer-total-war

Wood Elves are unique in being able to capture any territory in the game, however the Lookout will only have a garrison of 5 Low-Mid tier units and <s>unable to construct only other garrison buildings</s> constructing garrison only provides a couple more units but loose the important economy/military boost that lookout can provide.

Is there any other means to protect Lookouts far from base other than stationing an Army there which will also increase the upkeep of existing armies?

**EDIT**

**I have accepted an answer as it does answer my question but I still do hope there is a possibility there be a less known way to increase defence of lookouts.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There really isn't, lookouts are meant to be taken. As you can easily restore them if needed. The developers even mentioned this in their tips and tricks. They arent meant to be played as the other factions. Like the horde factions this is what makes them unique. The source and full article regarding wood elves can be found [here](https://forums.totalwar.com/discussion/188532/realm-of-the-wood-elves-tips-and-tricks-from-the-devs-spoilers).

> Don’t get too attached to your outposts. If you lose one you don’t always have to backtrack to reclaim it, moving forward is always a viable option! It’s better to have 20 semi-secure outposts that 5 secured ones, because those faction-wide bonuses form outpost buildings tend to stack fast!